# Changing signature of pre-production app on Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

My app is not yet in production. But I just released it to public alpha (no users yet). Anyway, I realized that I signed my app with the wrong key and I need to change that. What are the consequences. Does that mean I can no longer use my package name, my app name, what do I lose? Or will I be able to simply keep absolutely everything except the `apk`. thanks for any detailed help and loophole avoidances.

Comment: At least can I change the company name associated with the key? And still keep the app name and package name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [Things that cannot change blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html):

> Just as important as the manifest package name is the certificate that application is signed with. The signing certificate represents the author of the application. If you change the certificate an application is signed with, it is now a different application because it comes from a different author. This different application can’t be uploaded to [Google Play] as an update to the original application, nor can it be installed onto a device as an update.

Therefore if you'd like to change your signing key, you will also need to change your package name. Everything else can stay the same.